# Как высчитать степень?

Tags: математика, теория-чисел

[image: теорема]

я прочитал теорему как разложить простой число на множители и не понял нечего,

да я знаю что здесь min, max это функции которые принимают со своих параметров наибольшие или наименьшее значения: пример min(2,3,4) = 2;

НОД(a,b) - это просто наибольший общий делитель у этих чисел,
НОК(a,b) - наименьшее общее кратное у єтих 2 чисел, пример a = 14, b = 7, НОК(a,b) = 14;

тут по теореме мы разлажуем число (a) на множители чисел в степени,   множители чисел которые делят (a),
но я не понял как высчитать степень?

с теоремы я толком нечего не понял

Comment: Ну тебе ж дан пример. У `a` степень двойки - 3, у `b` - 1. Значит, у НОД степень двойки будет 1, а у НОК - соответственно 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот ваш конкретный пример...

```
2^3 3^1 5^4 13^1          2^1 5^3 13^3 19^1
```

Чтобы найти НОД - берем **минимальные** степени, т.е. это число

```
2^1 5^3 13^1 = 3250
```

Можно, чтоб было понятнее:

```
2^1 3^0 5^3 13^1 19^0
```

Чтобы найти НОК - берем **максимальные** степени, т.е. это число

```
2^3 3^1 5^4 13^3 19^1 = 626145000
```

Так понятнее?

Ну, а как получить степени...

195000 делим на 2, пока делится...

```
19500 = 2 * 97500 = 2 * 2 * 48750 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 24375
```

Т.е. степень 2 - 3.

24375 делим на 3, пока делится...

```
24375 = 3 * 8125
```

Т.е. степень при 3 - 1.

Далее делим на 5, пока делится...

```
8125 = 5 * 1625 = 5 * 5 * 325 = 5 * 5 * 5 * 65 = 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 13
```

Т.е. степень при 5 - 4. Ну, и понятно, что при 13 - 1. Итого:

```
195000 = 2^3 * 3^1 * 5^4 * 13^1
```

Comment: Я понял спасибо, ну и вообщем все эти расчеты с степенью с нахождением НОД, и НОК, только чтобы упростить расчеты наибольшего общего делителя, и наименьшего кратного у этих 2 числах a,b?

Comment: Нет, это скорее *теооретические* расчеты. *Практические* расчеты используют более простой [алгоритм Евклида](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0).